# Refrence request: What can lattices do for you? G. Birkhoff

Tags: reference-request

I am looking for an article called *What can lattices do for you?*, published by G. Birkhoff in *Trends in Lattice Theory, 1967*. I have been unsuccessful at obtaining it or the book that is contained in, so any references to where it can be found would be much appreciated.

Comment: I just looked, and this book is at the university library near where I live. I should be able to make a photocopy, and then scan the photocopy as a .pdf file, and then email the .pdf file to you in a few days if you still don't have a copy. I'll need your email address, which you can send to my email address (listed at my profile), if you are interested.

Comment: Wow, that's very generous of you. I would appreciate that a lot!

Comment: I emailed a .pdf scan of a photocopy of the paper to you a few minutes ago. You may want to delete your comment above with your email in it. (I have no idea why my email is not in my profile. I used to have it there, written in a way that current web robots would not be able to extract the correct address. Maybe someone higher up decided that emails should be taken out of profiles?)

Comment: Many thanks Dave!